# Center multi line legend in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, legend

[image]I have a legend with 4 items. I have put them into two rows and two columns. The labels for each legend entry are very different in length. How do I center each row of the legend? Currently Im using:

```
plt.legend(legend,labels,bbox_to_anchor=(-0.0, 1.22, 1.0, 0), mode="expand", scatterpoints=1)
```

From the figure, you can see that the rows of the legend are aligned so that the symbols are on top of each other. How can I center the rows so that each row is centered on the figure x axis?

Comment: What does "center each row of the legend" mean exactly? What is the required output?

Comment: I have slightly modified the original question, and added a figure to explain my question better

Comment: The legend is column based; each column's width is determined by the longest label. I would guess that it is possible to rewrite the legend code such that it will be row based and cut out the use of `HPacker` in it. But I'm not sure if it's worth the effort. Alternatively you may create several legends, one for each row and place them on top of each other; being used without legend frames, there is probably not so much of a difference to be seen.

Comment: Ok Thanks! How do I create several legends. When I tired this, it just puts them on top of each other

Comment: [Legend Guide](https://matplotlib.org/tutorials/intermediate/legend_guide.html#sphx-glr-tutorials-intermediate-legend-guide-py) - you may want to go through the [other tutorials](https://matplotlib.org/tutorials/index.html) first though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The legend is column based; each column's width is determined by the longest label. I would guess that it is possible to rewrite the legend code such that it will be row based and cut out the use of HPacker in it. But I'm not sure if it's worth the effort. Alternatively you may create several legends, one for each row and place them on top of each other; being used without legend frames (`frameon=False`).

To create two legends, you need to add the first one manually to the axes after having created the second legend. The position of the legend would e.g. be `loc="lower center", bbox_to_anchor=(0.5, yi)`, where `yi` is the vertical position which for the simple case here can be found by trial and error.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.arange(3)

markers = ["o","s","d","^"]
labels = ["Total", "Very very very long label", "Component 1", "Component 3"]
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

for i in range(4):
    ax.plot(x,i*(x+1), marker=markers[i], label=labels[i])

h, l = ax.get_legend_handles_labels()
kw = dict(ncol=2, loc="lower center", frameon=False)    
leg1 = ax.legend(h[:2],l[:2], bbox_to_anchor=[0.5,1.08],**kw)
leg2 = ax.legend(h[2:],l[2:], bbox_to_anchor=[0.5,1.00],**kw)
ax.add_artist(leg1)

fig.subplots_adjust(top=0.8)

plt.show()
```

[image]